# shutil.copy hiding the file

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, shutil

```
from shutil import copy
import os

print("Preparation: put 3 followpoint files in your skin's folder; followpoint.png, followpoint@2x.png, and followpointblank.png. I think these names are self explanatory enough.")
thingything = input("Enter your animation pattern (. = blank, - = line) (example: ...------..): ")
inputs = list(thingything)

for i in range(len(inputs)):
    if inputs[i] == ".":
        copy("followpointblank.png", "followpoint-" + str((i + 1)) + ".png")
    if inputs[i] == "-":
        copy("followpoint.png", "followpoint-" + str((i + 1)) + ".png")
        copy("followpoint@2x.png", "followpoint-" + str((i + 1)) + "@2x.png")

os.remove("followpoint.png")
os.remove("followpoint@2x.png")
os.remove("followpointblank.png")
```

Whenever I try to run this program, it ends up naming the files `.followpoint-1.png` instead of `followpoint-1.png` I'm using Windows 10. I don't want this.

Comment: i run this code and and it save without dot, just followpoint-1.png etc.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: A leading dot doesn't hide files in Windows.